# How to report a corrupt package on a specific apt repository?

Tags: package-management, repository, bug-reporting

I am trying to install "netatalk (2.2.5-1) i386" from tr.archive.ubuntu.com
But cannot continue to download after 78% and install fails. I have changed the repository and installed the package. But that file on that location seems corrupt because it gives same error each time I try to install it to another computer.
Question:
How to report this to get fixed?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no designated area for broken repositories. To report a broken repository I would recommend just posting it as a bug using the below site.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/